# How to use Custom Table API in Kentico 8.2

Tags: model-view-controller, content-management-system, kentico

I've created a website with an entry form for their pets( Pet Name, Age, Pet Type ) and then on the admin side I want to display the list of entries. My problem is when I'm importing the generated code to the ***~/CMSAPP_MVC/Models*** folder. The following error occured ( See Screenshot ).

[View Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1XGu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a generic error (not directly related to Kentico) which you get when you try to use class which is not "part" of your project. In most cases this is solved simply by **adding references** to your project.

Try adding "CMS.CustomTables" reference to your CMSApp_MVC project. You can find this binary in ~/bin folder.